# Auto-resizing web page to fit full height on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, viewport

I've been trying to get my web page automatically resized to fit the height on a mobile.
The left side of the screenshot shows the version with no scale while on the right side I used the "initial-scale" attribute to manually scale the page:

[image: screenshots without resize and resized]

This is how I achieved the right side of the screenshot:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, initial-scale=0.82">
```

I was wondering if there was a trick (html, css, js?) to automatically resize the display of my page without having to manually set "initial-scale"?
Any hints are very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: in CSS doing something like `html, body { height: 100vh; }` should make the body stretch to 100% of the view height

Comment: You should use this tag as Google's algorithm penalizes sites that don't, considering them as not mobile-friendly. But, typically, the initial scale should be 1.0, so not sure why you are shrinking it for mobile.

Comment: @EricHB I already tried that, unfortunately, this seems not to have any effect?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I would love to use initial-scale=1 - the way I did it was just a dirty workaround because I didn't know any better

Comment: what if you did `html, body { height: 82vh; }` and `inital-scale=1` to line up with the scale you want?

Comment: can you post the entire code of the page? (html,css, js)

Comment: 'height: 82vh' seemed to have no effect either, but the answer below solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change initital-scale with javascript, but the page won't rerender the change. In this case, I'd experiment with CSS scale property.

1. Give the main container with content some id. (for expample id="content")
2. Add script file (say resize.js)

```
const content = document.querySelector('#content');
content.style.transformOrigin = 'top left';

window.addEventListener('resize', recalculateScale);

function recalculateScale() {
  const windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  content.style.transform = `scale(${windowHeight / content.offsetHeight})`;
}

recalculateScale();
```

3. Add script tag to your html

```
<script src="resize.js"></script>
```

What this solution does is add listener to resize event. If you chage window dimensions, resize will run.

It gets the content element, sets css (you can also set it between `<style></style>` tags in document head), then listener is added. On resize event, function `recalculateScale` runs.

This will get `window` height and set CSS transform property to scale the content to some ratio. I tried `windowHeight/content.offsetHeight`, which is window height divided by the content container height. You can play a bit with the formula to get best result.